# Возврат строки из Main()

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, реально каким-то образом вернуть строку из программы?
Скажем, из одной программы я вызываю другую, которая должна передать какие-то данные в первую программу. msdn утверждает, что возвращаемый тип Main() либо void, либо int. Если какие-то варианты обхода, чтобы вернуть строку? 
Может быть это реально сделать как-то через идентификатор файла, в котором будет записана вся необходимая информация, и идентификатор которого будет возвращать вторая программа?

Comment: int - для системы. Запишите вашу строку в файл одной программой, другой - читайте

Comment: Вернуть откуда? Куда?

Comment: При обмене данными между программами можно использовать error-result (в батнике), console, разделяемая память, DDE, pipe, socket и многое другое.

Comment: @Sublihim, это все здорово, но вот только надо каким-то образом тогда передавать адрес на файл. Скажем система подразумевается такая: есть определенный круг возможностей одной программы, и если надо совершать что-то, что не входит в стандартную задачу, то она запускает  стороннюю программу. Дело в том, что сторонних программ может быть несколько. И как тогда явно вторая программа укажет первой программе, где искать тот самый адрес? Единственная мысль которая меня сейчас посетила - это чтобы первая программа в качестве параметра передала второй программе абсолютный адрес файла для записи.

Comment: @OlegKlezovich, страшные вещи приходят вам в голову :)

Comment: Как вы хотите связать две программы? Если на прямую, то можно прямо в `exec` подставить параметры.

Comment: @OlegKlezovich пишут, что можно использовать для этих целей стандартный консольный вывод что то вроде Console.WriteLine("Парамерт: Моя строка"); А потом получать ее по параметру. Почему бы не использовать общую библиотеку для связки программ? Или не получать доступ к процессу, если он запущен?

Comment: @Sublihim отчего же??? Раз нельзя строку вернуть, но можно ее передать в виде параметра, то почему бы не передать адрес, по которому я могу найти интересующую меня информацию. Так получается одна будет знать куда записывать, а другая будет знать откуда читать.

Comment: @user2455111 а можете привезти пример? Желательно для WinForms.

Comment: @OlegKlezovich вообще-то это был консольный вариант был

Comment: @OlegKlezovich для winform могу предложить записывать строку в текстбокс, потом получат handle окна через winapi и доступ до текстбокса )) вот тут пример есть http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615105/getting-text-entered-in-textbox-of-other-applications-using-c-sharp

Comment: @user2455111 как-то уж слишком заморочено... по мне так проще параметр передать...=)

Comment: А вообще задача изначально как стоит? Просто судя по вопросу - надо из программы **вернуть** строку, а по комменту выше - **передать**. Так вот есть некая программа А и набор других программ, B, C, D и что? Нужно чтоб А умела вызывать B, C или D?

Comment: Скажу так, строку можно вернуть в консоль. Из консоли её получить так `му.exe > 1.txt` а далее уже скриптом делайте со строкой что хотите. На js есть примеры где с консоли можно сразу в переменную записать значение, там же можно и запустить. bat- возможно можно, не уверен.

Comment: @BlackWitcher да. Но при этом программы B, C и D могла возвращать в А какие-то свои значения (например, в виде строки). Но поскольку Main() не может вернуть строку, то я предложил передать из программы A в виде аргумента в другие программы адрес файла, в который программа B, C или D сможет сохранить свои результаты, а A потом сможет эти значения из этого файла прочитать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартным способом вывода информации в консольных программах является т.н. *стандартный поток вывода* (он же "стандартный вывод", stdout).

Вывод в него делается через семейство методов `Console.Write` или через объект `Console.Out`.

Если в первая программа запускает вторую - она может использовать перенаправление стандартного вывода (см [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx)) чтобы эту самую строку считать. Отмечу, что по соглашению, дополнительный поток, называемый stderr (доступный через `Console.Error`) не перенаправляется и доступен для вывода сообщений пользователю даже когда stdout перенаправлен в другую программу.

Если обе программы запускаются из оболочки командной строки - можно использовать пайпы чтобы соединить стандартный вывод одной программы со стандартным вводом другой:

```
program1 | program2
```

В такой случае все что одна программа вывела через `Console.Write` другая сможет считать через `Console.Read`.

Comment: а как бы с winforms?

Comment: @OlegKlezovich а в чем разница?

Answer (score 0):

Вывод на консоль и pipe не устраивают?

```
echo ping 8.8.8.8 | cmd
```

Comment: А можно пример (если несложно) как это работает?

Comment: @OlegKlezovich, готово.

Comment: 1. http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html 2. https://rsdn.org/article/winshell/batanyca.xml

Comment: как-то не очевидно... можно поподробней расписать?

Comment: Одна программа делает Console.WriteLine, а другая - Console.ReadLine. При этом первая при запуске ставится до пайпа, а вторая - после.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/135591)

Comment: @Naumov, почему не является?

Comment: Эх не хватает в очереди проверок самого вопроса перед глазами, а то ваш ответ выглядит как коментарий

Comment: @Naumov, вообще-то он там под ответом в полупрозрачном состоянии.

Comment: странно не замечал, ладно сорян тогда... думаю не стоит больше офтоп разводить.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю вам поможет [MemoryMappedFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx), нужные данные передавать сериализацией или другим методом.
А то, что Main() возвращает int - это называется ERRORLEVEL.